# Returning from Ubuntu SDK full screen mode

Tags: ubuntu-sdk

I have a little problem in switching back to normal mode with ubuntu-sdk  IDE. 
*esc* doesn't work???

Comment: Shift + Ctl + f11 is the solution :)
This thread could be closed. I found the answer by opening the sdk in terminal. This instance opened in normal mode and just checked _window > full screen_

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu.com! Please post your solution as an Answer and accept it, so we know this issue has been solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to switch back to the normal mode